# INNER JOIN in visual basic with ComboBox value in SQL string

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, combobox, inner-join

i have a problem with an INNER JOIN in Visual Basic when i try to use a combobox value in SQL string.

This code work:

```
{
Private Sub ComboBoxMatricola_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBoxMatricola.TextChanged
        Dim connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        connection.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = DBManutenzione.accdb"
        connection.Open()

        Dim SqlCmd = "SELECT DatiManutenzione.Fase, DatiManutenzione.IDGrandezza, DatiManutenzione.FrequenzaGrandezza, DatiManutenzione.Descrizione, DatiManutenzione.FrequenzaTemporale, Macchine.Matricola FROM Macchine INNER JOIN (DatiManutenzione INNER JOIN Manutenzione ON DatiManutenzione.ID = Manutenzione.IDManutenzioneProgrammata) ON Manutenzione.Matricola = Macchine.Matricola"
        command = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(SqlCmd, connection)

        Dim readerQuery As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
        readerQuery = command.ExecuteReader()
        Dim Count As Integer
        Count = 0
        While readerQuery.Read()
            Count = Count + 1
        End While
        MsgBox(Count)
        connection.Close()
    End Sub
}
```

When i modify SqlCmd like this:

```
...ON Manutenzione.Matricola ='" & ComboBoxMatricola.Text & "'"
```

I have this error:

JOIN expression not supported

I have to read a value of ON condition from a combobox.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

If im not mistaken, you cannot do that directly in your `SQL JOIN` , how ever there's a way to do that in `WHERE` condition.. depending on how you apply the logic.

something like `WHERE Macchine.Matricola = ComboBoxMatricola.Text`